# Алгоритм погрузки бетонных колец

Tags: python, c#, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Задача такая: 
На вход подаётся размер грузовой машины и её грузоподъемность, а так же количество бетонных колец, которые необходимо отправить.
Кольца разного размера, веса, так же имеют различные способы укладки друг на друга, но заранее известны все возможные виды.

На выход количество рейсов со списком того какие кольца укомплектованы и графически как укомплектованы.

Comment: [задача укладки рюкзака](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5), их тут две даже: по весу и по геометрии. Вопрос слишком общий, похож больше на крупное техзадание - я бы не стал отвечать на такой подробно. Читайте литературу, пробуйте. В СССР за оптимизацию кроя металла по геометрии институты премии получали, а вы думаете, что вам тут легко ответят без подробностей про конкретные параметры, угадают как заправские телепаты ваши подробности и сразу в точку попадут с наилучшим алгоритмом? Наивно.

Comment: Это вы задание дали? Фрилансеры на другом сайте и за деньги.

Comment: Мне кажется, что единственный способ найти оптимальное решение - метод полного перебора. Только перебирать абсолютно все варианты укладки, количества и тд, чтоб они максимально подходили по грузоподьъемности

Answer (score 0):

Если в кратце у нас есть лист с Рейсами класса Рейс, у Рейс есть поле лист класса груз в который добавляется список Грузов класса груз, свойство масса возвращающее вес Рейса.

В целом дальше прости идёт прогон по списку грузов, которые нужно отправить, если в рейсе есть место и грузоподъёмность позволяет, то добавляем в груз в лист грузов Рейса обновляя вес груза и запоминая центр. Так же центр отсчитываем с правой стороны, а потом с левой, чтобы плотнее вставали.

Первый Центр находится на координате x = r, y = r. Последующие находятся вот как, ежи прибавить центр к предидущему центру + предидущий радиус и мы не вылезем за длину грузовика, то по теореме пифагора находим `y` который нужно прибавить, чтобы получить новый центр. На рисунке `c` равна сумме радиусов в квадрате - (длина грузовика - радиус предыдущего - радиус текущего) в квадрате.Главное учесть что грузы могут быть поставлены рядом из-за того что сумма радиусов меньше длинны грузов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как мы загрузили грузы в ряд, но масса осталась, начинаем грузить заново, только в центры. На этой ноте я прекращу вещание, так как вряд ли смогу что-то внятно объяснить.